# jqgrid add personal button in navgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid and I would add in the navgrid a personal function with a specific button.
Can I do it? How?

```
    jQuery("#tabGrid").jqGrid({
    .....
    }).navGrid('#pagerPrivati',
{}, //options
{
}, // edit options
{
}, // add options
{
}, // del options
{
} // search options
);
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can skip the last empty `{}` parameters of `navGrid`. So you can just rewrite your code above to the following

```
jQuery("#tabGrid").jqGrid({
.....
}).navGrid('#pagerPrivati');
```

To you main question. You can use [navButtonAdd](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_buttons) to add your custom button to the grid. 
The examples from [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_buttons) seems me clear enough. One more [example](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithColumnChooser2.htm) from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996602/how-to-properly-attach-event-to-close-dialog-for-columns-chooser-of-jqgrid/6997103#6997103) which I wrote today could be probably also helpful for you.

One uses typically the values for the `buttonicon` parameter in the form: `buttonicon: "ui-icon-calculator"` where the `"ui-icon-calculator"` are the name of CSS class which define an icon. Mostly one uses the jQuery UI classes which you can see for example [here](http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.8.15/tests/static/icons.html).