# Make column visible in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a grid with 50+ columns. I would like to enable the user to select a column they want displayed (with a dropdown or some such).
Is there any function to make a certain column be visible [to the user] e.g. scroll the grid to the column location or move the column?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [columnChooser](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jquery_ui_methods#column_chooser) method. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901210/is-there-a-full-working-example-for-a-jqgrid-columnchooser/5901459#5901459) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996602/how-to-properly-attach-event-to-close-dialog-for-columns-chooser-of-jqgrid/6997103#6997103) which include the demo for more details.

Comment: OK, thanks. But no way of just making a certain column appear?